# Calculator in C# input from keyboard using "&" in text property

Tags: c#, input, keyboard

I'm developing a calculator in visual studio 2017. Everything is working fine, but input from keyboard isn't working properly. 
I use "&" in text property of a button, and it works, but problem is that it's printing on the screen like "&1 + &2". I attach a code and images so you guys can see what's happening.

1 - [result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWws8.jpg)

2 - [usage of "&" symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x87Cg.jpg)

Thanks in advance,
Best regards, 
Ram

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Double resultado_value = 0; // result is zero in the beginning 
        String operationPerformed = ""; 
        bool is_pressed = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((textBox_Result.Text == "0") || (is_pressed))
                textBox_Result.Clear();

            is_pressed = false;
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            if (button.Text == ".") //to avoid repetitive dots
            { 
               if(!textBox_Result.Text.Contains("."))
                   textBox_Result.Text = textBox_Result.Text + button.Text;

            }else
            textBox_Result.Text = textBox_Result.Text + button.Text;

        }

        private void operator_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;

            if (resultado_value != 0) //if result value not equal to zero
            {
                button15.PerformClick();
                operationPerformed = button.Text;
                labelCurrentOperation.Text = resultado_value + " " + operationPerformed;
                is_pressed = true;
            }
            else
            {
                operationPerformed = button.Text;
                resultado_value = Double.Parse(textBox_Result.Text);
                labelCurrentOperation.Text = resultado_value + " " + operationPerformed;
                is_pressed = true;
            }
        }
        //Clear entry
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox_Result.Text = "0";
        }
        //button Clear
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;//can't find color "control"
            textBox_Result.Text = "0";
            resultado_value = 0;
        }
        // equal button
        private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (operationPerformed)
            {
                case "+":
                  //  this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;//form change color to red
                    textBox_Result.Text = (resultado_value + Double.Parse(textBox_Result.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "-":
                //    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;
                    textBox_Result.Text = (resultado_value - Double.Parse(textBox_Result.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "X":
                 //   this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
                    textBox_Result.Text = (resultado_value * Double.Parse(textBox_Result.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "÷":
                  //  this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet;
                    textBox_Result.Text = (resultado_value / Double.Parse(textBox_Result.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            resultado_value = Double.Parse(textBox_Result.Text);
            labelCurrentOperation.Text = "";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void labelCurrentOperation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you _expect_ it to do? & doesn't mean anything in a textbox...

Comment: @john Thanks for you comment! When I put "&" in text, it start accepting input from keyboard. but problem is that it's being printed in result area.

Comment: As a simple solution, put the values you want to actually add to the textbox in the "Tag" property of the button, and then add button.Tag.ToString() instead of button.Text. A better solution is to handle each button separately and call through to another method. e.g. clicking on 1 calls a method you create: Insert("1"), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly then what you want to do is catch keypresses at the Form level. If this is what you want you should set the KeyPreview Property of your Form to true and override the OnKeyPress Method of the Form or add an Event Handler of KeyPressed and assign this to the Forms KeyPressed Event and do your thing there.

If you want me to provide an example let me know.

Ram Pawar I have written a quick example for you.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Formkeypress
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            KeyPreview = true;
        }

        protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyPress(e);
            if (e.KeyChar == 'r') BackColor = Color.Red;
            if (e.KeyChar == 'b') BackColor = Color.Blue;
            if (e.KeyChar == 'g') BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
```

}

Basicly if you type 'r' here the Form will change its Background color to Red. Typing 'b' will change it to Blue, typing 'g' will change it to Green.

Please note that you have to set KeyPreview to true in the constructor for this to work.

I override the OnKeyPress event here as this is the prefered way to add logic to an event when deriving from a Control or Form. You can however just attach a KeyPress event handler to the Form if you wish with the same code block as the OnKeyPress method.

Also rermove the '&'s from your Text Properties.

Hope this help
Danny

Comment: thank you very much, can you please send an example? 
I'm very new programmer, so it would be great if you explain me bit more, where should I add this "keypress" event?
Thanks

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: Thank you Dannyhut, I tried that with numbers, but program stops working. it works with letters.
What exactly I want is that I want that my calculator accepts input from my keyboard, example "1" + "2".. so on... if you check pictures I attached would understand better. 
Thanks

Comment: Ram Pawar, not sure why this doesn't work with numbers, it does on my Computer, I just tried. KeyChar is a character type so you need to check for '1' not 1 in you if statement, eg if (e.KeyChar == '1') not == 1.

Comment: I got it Danny!! Thank you very much!! Problem was that I was trying typing "1" but it should be '4', with single quotes signs. It's strange! I've Portuguese keyboard, maybe that's why. 
Now I'll try to make it work with numbers and do calculator's operations.

Comment: Great I'm glad it worked. Please don't forget to mark the question as answered. If you have any other problems using it let me know.